# Is there a way to make part of template string bold in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to make part of a template string bold in my React app. Here is the very much simplified and  **only** relevant part of the code:

```
function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  let {Error: error } = apiResponse

  if (error === 'Too many results.') {
    error = `Too many results for the search: <b>"${input}"</b>.`
  }

  return (
    <>           
     {error}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

My problem is that instead of making `${input}` bold  `b` tags are output to html -> `<b>some value</b>`. Is there a way to make it work in React app. It works in regular html/javascript but fails to work in React. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn’t need to be a string. You can directly put the HTML in there:

```
error = <>Too many results for the search: <b>"{input}"</b>.</>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strong` tag rather than `b` tag. [refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong)

For example:

```
error = `Too many results for the search: <strong>"${input}"</strong>.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your code is written, you might be able to do something like this:

```js
function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  let {Error: error } = apiResponse

  return (
    <>           
     {
       error === 'Too many results.'
         ? <>Too many results for the search: <b>"{input}"</b>.</>
         : error
     }
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Otherwise, try react's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```js
function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  let {Error: error } = apiResponse

  if (error === 'Too many results.') {
    error = `Too many results for the search: <b>"${input}"</b>.`
  }

  return (
    <>           
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: error}} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Note that if input contains any html, it will be displayed too, so if you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTHL`, you have to be careful with html-encoding `input`